# Create two Pandas DataFrames based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create two Pandas data frames.

The data I'm dealing with is days of the month. The following example shows days that cross over two months. You can see that the first day is the 19th of the month. This column of data then carries on until the 19th of the next month.

I need a way to break the data into two data frames - The first df goes from 19-30, the second df goes from the 01-19.

This is my df at the moment.

```
Days
0     19
1     20
2     21
3     22
4     23
5     24
6     25
7     26
8     27
9     28
10    29
11    30
12     1
13     2
14     3
15     4
16     5
17     6
18     7
19     8
20     9
21    10
22    11
23    12
24    13
25    14
26    15
27    16
28    17
29    18
30    19
```

I need the data frames to look like this:

```
df - Number 1

0     19
1     20
2     21
3     22
4     23
5     24
6     25
7     26
8     27
9     28
10    29
11    30


df - Number 2

0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     6
6     7
7     8
8     9
9     10
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
15    16
16    17
17    18
18    19
```

I've tried using the `.shift` method to check previous values are larger than the next, but this only works to find when the month ends.

```
timesheet_df['match'] = timesheet_df.Days > timesheet_df.Days.shift()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `diff` and `cumsum` create the key , the `groupby` save the sub-group into `dict`

```
d={x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.Days.diff().lt(0).cumsum())}
```

Comment: Hi WeNYoBen - Could you explain the workings further please?

Comment: @DaveStark if the number start decrease which diff is negative , the `df.Days.diff().lt(0)` will be true , then we cumsum , that mean we start a new group